# How can a Java app accepts a server certificate seamlessly?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, ldapconnection

Most Web browsers that support SSL have a list of CAs whose certificates they will automatically accept. If a browser encounters a certificate whose authorizing CA is in the list, the browser will automatically accept the certificate, and establish a SSL connection to the site.

There is a Java 1.6 client, running on JBoss 7, which is required to make SSL connection to LDAP server.  Since the client is on production, if the LDAP server updates its certificate without notifying me to update the certificate accordingly on JBoss, the client will fail.  My question is: how can I securely connect(ssl) to LDAP in a similar way the browser “accepts” the certificate seamlessly?

I don’t know if this is feasible in Java. But, any thoughts and feedbacks are all welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a default truststore that contains all the trusted certificates. This is under `%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\cacert` and has all the trusted CA certificates (Verisign etc).
So if your client `https` application tries to connect to a server that deploys a certificate signed by these issuers you would have no issue (same as happens with your browser).
Now to your problem. You don't mention enough information about your `LDAP` server.
I can think of the following:

1. The LDAP server deploys a certificate signed by some CA (not one of
   the known ones).
2. The LDAP server deploys a self-signed certificate

For case (1) all you need to do is add the certificate *of the signer* to your truststore (i.e. the certificate of the issure that signed the certificate of your LDAP server). If the LDAP server changes certificate, you would be *unaffected* provided that it gets the certificate from the same CA which you would have set now as trusted. This trusted certificate could be added in `cacerts` but the recommended solution is to use your own separate truststore, import it and set it in JVM to override the default `cacerts`. Plenty of example in Google.

For case (2) this is a really bad setup and are in trouble as you would need to actually update the truststore manually each time the `LDAP` server changes certificate.

But in any case I can only assume that the certificate changes due to expiration? I can't think of another reason (except compromise of private key but this is not the problem here from your description)

Comment: The LDAP certificate is signed by a well-known CA. The certificate changes because it is expired. I think the solution would be the one suggested to case 1, right? "...add the certificate of the signer to your truststore..." Is this also known as "root certificate"?

Comment: @WillL:You can see if this well known CA is already included as part of java's default truststore.If it is then you should be ok.If it is not then I suggest that you don't import it but configure a truststore with that CA's certificate

Comment: Cratylus, actually it is a new cert. In java, can I make a secure connection to LDAP, and the Java client would accept and save the cert without someone manually updating the cert on client? Is this too ambitious to do? -thx

Comment: This is possible if you write code yourself, **but** this is completely **wrong** from security perspective.The idea is that the server's trusted certificate is *pre-installed* and you validate the certificate the server will send you in the SSL handshake with the one you already consider as trusted.If you "dynamically" accept the server's certificate as trusted, then SSL becomes useless

Comment: I shouldn’t say the client “just” accept the certificate.  Once the client receives the certificate, it still has to validate if the certificate is signed by a trust CA. I agree your point. Otherwise, it just defeats the purpose of SSL handshake.

What you mean by “the server’s trusted certificate is pre-installed”?

Comment: @WillL:If the issuing CA's certificate is already part of your truststore you are ok